# Using selenium code How to send data into textfield in bootstrap modal

Tags: selenium, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to send data into textfield in bootstrap modal using selenium code

In the past,I've tried by using xpath and id attribute 
But its throwing an error message that Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

```
1)driver.findElement(By.id("diningTableNumber")).sendKeys("TN");
2)driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-body']//input[@id='diningTableNumber']")).sendKeys("TN");
```

I expect the output as the  which data i have been trying to save in textfield it should get submitted and added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to induce a `WebDriverWait`:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("diningTableNumber"))).sendKeys("TN");
```

(you will need the following imports):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

Also, I've put in a 10 seconds timeout, you can change it as needed.